# Pass local video to mediametadataretriever throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, mediametadataretriever

In my android app I want to extract video frames. I am using MediaMetaDataRetriever for the same.

How I set datasource

```
 Log.d("DEBUG", videoPathUri.getPath());
 metadataRetriever.setDataSource(mContext, videoPathUri);
```

Here is the log output

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.live.hootout/files/HootVideos/10701.mp4
```

How can I load video stored in android data folder into mediametadataretriever?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
File file = new File(context.getDataDir(),filename);
```

Comment: Hi. I solved it using inputstream. I'll post how I did it.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it.

```
File file = new File(videoPathUri.getPath());
try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
      metadataRetriever.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
       Log.d("DEBUG", "FileNotFoundException", e);
    }catch(IOException ea){
       Log.d("DEBUG", "IOException", ea);
    }
```